# Using Complex Types vs. Individual Properties in C# Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm creating an application where using the Entity framework using code-first. I have created a few models but before I go any further I want to verify some things. The models I created are for things like products, customers and orders. I also have created some models that I am using as types, like for addresses. For example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string AddressLineOne { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineTwo { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Is this preferable over creating individual properties such ShipToAddress, ShipToState, etc.? I am pretty new to web development and don't want to have to start this over because of some problems cause by this down the road. Thanks for any help in advance and I apologize in advance if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its much better way, then creating individual properties for ShipToState etc. This way you would be able to use the Address class with other classes as well.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick reply. Just a quick side note, should I save models like the Address class along with all of the other Entities in the file structure or should they have their own folder?

Comment: I would  have them in the same folder as other entities